# Compare items at the same index between 2 lists and append the min value to a 3rd list?

Tags: python

```
def func_0(arr_1, arr_2):
    arr_3 = list()
    for num1, num2 in zip(arr_1, arr_2):
        if(arr_1[num1]<=arr_2[num2]):
            arr_3.append(arr_1[num1])
        else:
            arr_3.append(arr_2[num2])
    return arr_3
```

Let's say the first list `arr_1=[5,9,3]` and the second one `arr_2=[2,16,4]`. The output should be `arr_3=[2,9,3]` and I've been trying to use a for loop to compare the 2 values on the same index from 2 different lists and append the lesser value to a 3rd list but I can't get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made it too complicated, just append the `min` of each pair of numbers that the `zip` function produces.

```
def func_0(arr_1, arr_2):
    arr_3 = list()
    for pair in zip(arr_1, arr_2):
        arr_3.append(min(pair))
    return arr_3
```

If you want to make it really short, you can use:

```
def func_1(a1, a2):
    return list(map(min, zip(a1, a2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done very simply with `numpy` if you wish:

```
np.min((a1, a2), axis=0)
```

Where `a1` and `a2` are numpy arrays, and a third (min) array is returned.

Comment: fine, but this involves installing a third-party module when it might not make much difference, unless the lists are big and in this case numpy can improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the iteration variables num1 and num2.

```
def func_0(arr_1, arr_2):
    arr_3 = list()
    for num1, num2 in zip(arr_1, arr_2):
        if num1 < num2:
            arr_3.append(num1)
        else:
            arr_3.append(num2)
    return arr_3

arr_1=[5, 9, 3]  
arr_2=[2, 16, 4] 

arr_3 = func_0(arr_1, arr_2)

print(arr_3)

[2, 9, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`num1 and num2` contains element from list so no need to write as  `arr_1[num1] and arr_2[num2])`

```
  def func_0(arr_1, arr_2):
        arr_3 = list()
        for num1, num2 in zip(arr_1, arr_2):
            print(num1, num2)
            if(num1 <= num2):
                arr_3.append(num1)
            else:
                arr_3.append(num2)
        return arr_3
```

Though you can use `min()` function to get minimum value between two.

```
def func_0(arr_1, arr_2):
    arr_3 = list()
    for num1, num2 in zip(arr_1, arr_2):
        arr_3.append(min(num1,num2))
    return arr_3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a basic list-comprehension:

```
def func_1(a1, a2):
    return [min(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(a1, a2)]
```

First list comprehensions make code easier to read, second it's often faster than other builtins.